# How to do a hql query for create a new object containing a List<Object>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, hql

I'm working on my first spring boot project, I'm trying to create custom query I already arrive to do the following:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.openclassrooms.lesamisdelagrimpe.repositories.dao.SiteResume(min(voie.hauteurDeLaVoie), max(voie"
          + ".hauteurDeLaVoie),min(voie.cotationDeLaVoie),max(voie.cotationDeLaVoie)) from Site si left join si.listeDeSecteurs "
          + "secteur "
          + "left join secteur.listeVoieDuSecteur voie where si.idSite = :id group by si.idSite") SiteResume getSiteResume(@Param(value = "id") int id);
```

but now i would like to create an object containing a `list<>` I started with something like that :

```
select new com.openclassrooms.lesamisdelagrimpe.controller.dto
 .SiteFilteredResultDto(list(si.regionDuSite),
  max(voie.cotationDeLaVoie),max(si.listeDeSecteurs)) from Site si 
left join si.listeDeSecteurs secteur 
left join secteur.listeVoieDuSecteur 
voie
```

and I tried that :

```
select new com.openclassrooms.lesamisdelagrimpe.controller.dto.SiteFilteredResultDto((select si.regionDuSite from Site si),
(SELECT voie.cotationDeLaVoie from Site si left join si.listeDeSecteurs secteur left join secteur.listeVoieDuSecteur voie order by voie.cotationDeLaVoie asc),
(select count(secteur) from Site si left join si.listeDeSecteurs secteur)from Site si order by si.idSite
```

Any suggestions will be appericiated!